# How to find and replace fixed 3 characters on different line (notepad++)

Tags: html, notepad++

I have that text :

```
↓
<button id="upbtn" class="btnx">→</button><br><br>
<button id="downbtn" class="btny">➤</button><br>
<a href="#">←</a><br><br><br>
<a href="#">←</a><br><br><br>
```

And i want :

```
↓
<button id="upbtn" class="btnx">»</button><br><br>
<button id="downbtn" class="btny">➤</button><br>
<a href="#">«</a><br><br><br>
<a href="#">«</a><br><br><br>
```

I used to multi line find replace on notepad++ and used regular expression but failed.

Comment: What regex did you try? Did you use \n or \r\n or other combinations?

Comment: Yes, but failed.

Comment: I have that text :
↓
button id="upbtn" class="btnx"→/buttonbrbr
button id="downbtn" class="btny"➤/buttonbr 
a href="#"←/abrbrbr
a href="#"←/abrbrbr
.
.
.
And i want :
↓
button id="upbtn" class="btnx"»/buttonbrbr
button id="downbtn" class="btny"➤/buttonbr 
a href="#"«/abrbrbr
a href="#"«/abrbrbr
.
.
.
I used to multi line find replace on notepad++ and used regular expression but failed.

Comment: Please make sure that your question is edited correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using regular expressions you need to use either `\n` or `\r\n` to target line breaks, depending on your platform or editor settings.

Here is an example using `\r\n`

Find

```
↓\r\n<button id="upbtn" class="btnx">→</button><br><br>\r\n<button id="downbtn" class="btny">➤</button><br>\r\n<a href="#">←</a><br><br><br>\r\n<a href="#">←</a><br><br><br>
```

Replace

```
↓\r\n<button id="upbtn" class="btnx">»</button><br><br>\r\n<button id="downbtn" class="btny">➤</button><br>\r\n<a href="#">«</a><br><br><br>\r\n<a href="#">«</a><br><br><br>
```

This is all assuming that your text is exactly as presented in your question